# ASP.Net MVC - how to save and retrieve data from two tables in one database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to achieve is like this:

1. Fill up a form in view
2. Save data into table1 with columns:

   ```
   Id|OperationNumber|Name|ContactNo
   ```

   table1 `Id` is the primary key
3. Save data into table2 with columns:

   ```
   ReferenceId|OperationNumber
   ```

   `ReferenceId` is the primary key of datatype `uniqueidentifier`

"OperationNumber" column in both table is related. when data is saved in table1, OperationNumber will also save in table2 together with autogenerated `ReferenceId` (`uniqueidentifier`)

Retrieving process is:

1. input `ReferenceId` as search
2. Display all the details from table1 and table2 in result view

So that is my problem, how do i save and retrieve data in two tables?

Here's what I currently have:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(RefViewModel myViewModel)
{
     db.Table1.Add(myViewModel.Ref);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Model:

```
public class RefViewModel
{
     public Table1 Ref { get; set; }
     public string OperationNumber { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}
```

In the above code can save only in table1. so what to do in order for me to save two tables?

(oh and btw. as you may have noticed the "Bind(Include =" is nowhere, I have disabled it because I'm getting null values when saving into database. so, anyways. that's not the problem anymore here. just mentioning)

Database is SQL Server

Edit: as for retrieving data

SearchController:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
{
     var myRef = (from x in db.Table1
                  where x.OperationNumber.Contains(searchString)
                  select x).FirstOrDefault();
     return View(myRef);
}
```

That returns details when I input the `operationnumber`. So the problem is how to retrieve details from two tables when I input only `referenceId`?

Comment: Which method you're using to save in current way? To retrieve details in 2 or more tables, use `join` with `equals` to foreign key fields e.g. `from x in db.Table1 join y in db.Table2 on x.referenceId equals y.referenceId where ... select ...`.

Comment: or.. you can create a view on your database... add it into your EF model and return  the view result as model

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using stored procedures. Define two property classes to represent two tables and use inheritance as follows.

```
public class Tablel
{
     public string ID { get; set; }
     public string OperationNumber { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}

public class Table2 extend Table1
{
     public string ReferenceID { get; set; }
     public string OperationNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Now you can use stored procedures to save and retrieve data from database. Use join when you retrieve data from database and you can use two separate queries when save data to two tables.

Comment: what u mean by, "use two separate queries when save data to two tables"? how do i do that in controller

Comment: That is why we use stored procedures. You can execute the stored procedure and within the SP you can write two queries.

Answer (score 0):

From c# metadata of `DbContext.SaveChanges()`:-

Returns:
        //     The number of objects written to the underlying database.

so basically you will do something like this:-

```
public ActionResult Create(RefViewModel myViewModel)
{
     db.Table1.Add(myViewModel.Ref);
     var t1 = db.SaveChanges();

     Table2 t2 = new Table2
     {
        OperationNumber = t1.OperationNumber
     };

     db.Table2.Add(t2);
     db.SaveChanges();

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

when the SaveChanges is called, it returns all the objects saved to the database so when you call SaveChanges for the first time, it will return a Table1 object and with that Table1 object you will populate the OperationNumber property of Table2 and call SaveChanges again.

Answer (score 0):

if your operationnumber is unique then use this query on store procedure, you can found data using ReferenceID

```
Select * from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.OperationNumber = t2.OperationNumber
where t2.ReferenceID = @pReferenceID
```